# Test of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt[3]{k}}$ converge?

Can someone help me with this particular question? I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Share your thoughts. Surely this looks like something you've covered recently.

Comment: @zhw.Well as per nth term test, the series should converge but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)?

Comment: The nth term test proves that, if the limit is greater than 0, the series diverges. However, the converse is not true. A series with a limit of 0 does not necessarily converge; it can converge or diverge. For example, the limit of 1/n as n approaches infinity is 0; however, the sum of 1/n diverges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that this is an alternating series because of the $(-1)^k$ term. Can you show that 
$$ \big\lvert (-1)^k\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k}}\big\rvert=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k}}\to 0$$
as $k\to\infty$? If you can show this, then the series converges by the alternating series test.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Alternating series test.